# What was the largest object ever manipulated by the force?

Tags: star-wars

When Luke is undergoing training on Dagobah, he famously tries and fails to lift his X-Wing from the swamp:

> LUKE: I can't.  It's too big.
>
> YODA: Size matters not. Look at me. Judge me by my size, do you? Hm? Mmmm.

Yoda then lifts it for him and the story continues.

Now, while Yoda says size matters not, I'm assuming there *are* limitations. In other words, I'm assuming a Jedi can't stand aboard a spaceship and lift/manipulate an entire planet. Or can they? Or how about something even smaller - could a Jedi lift/manipulate a Coruscant skyscraper?

What was the largest object every manipulated using the force in the Star Wars universe, books, movies or otherwise? I'd be interested in either largest as in size, or largest as in weight.

Comment: What about pushing an entire fleet out of the Yavin system? Would that count?

Comment: Survey says: George  Lucus's ego.

Comment: The "biggest display of power" question is broader than telekinetic manipulation. The "limits" question is more focused on the telekinesis.

Comment: If anyone has played the starwars kotor games, in the second one darth nihilus can use the force to devour planets. Although this isn't part of the standard canon